# JS: innerHTML and href with parameters

Tags: javascript

I have two questions:

1. how do I pass the parameter in this href? id is a previously declared variable with value. I tried as written below but the id is not read
2. Also, how can I read this id that I pass in the new html page (detailsbook)?

```js
document.getElementById("book").innerHTML = "<a href='detailsbook.html?id=+id'>"+ myArray.Item.title + "</a>";
```

Thank you all.

Comment: You need to break the string with `"` quotes just like you did for `title`

Comment: The same way as with the title o.O

Comment: You might benefit some legibility by using template literals as well

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/get-the-values-from-the-get-parameters-javascript/979995#979995 for question 2.

Comment: myArr.Item.Title is the title I have to click on, but I have to pass the id, they are two different things.

Comment: But you concatenate strings the same way.

Comment: `+ id` should not be inside the quotes, it should be outside the quotes.

Comment: i tried, but i get detailsbook.html?id=

Comment: If you wrote `?id=" + id + "'>"` it should have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to substitute variables into a string is with template literals rather than concatenation.

```js
document.getElementById("book").innerHTML = `<a href='detailsbook.html?id=${id}>${myArray.Item.title}</a>`;
```

Comment: 10 seconds faster 

Comment: perfect thanks. You immediately understood what my problem is. Last question: how can I read the past id in this new html page (so in etailsbook.html)?

Comment: See the link I gave above in the comment

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest approach is to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
document.getElementById("book").innerHTML = 
  `<a href="detailsbook.html?id=${id}">${myArray.Item.title}</a>`;
```